# Taking my MVC to the next level: DI and Unit of Work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unity-container, ioc-container

I have looked at simpler applications like Nerddinner and ContactManager as well as more complicated ones like Kigg. I understand the simpler ones and now I would like to understand the more complex ones.

Usually the simpler applications have repository classes and interfaces (as loosely coupled as they can get) on top of either LINQtoSQL or the Entity Framework. The repositories are called from the controllers to do the necessary data operations.

One common pattern I see when I examine more complicated applications like Kigg or Oxite is the introduction of (I am only scratching the surface here but I have to start somewhere):

- IOC DI (in Kigg's case Unity)
- Web Request Lifetime manager
- Unit of Work

Here are my questions:

I understand that in order to truly have a loosely coupled application you have to use something like Unity. But it also seems like the moment you introduce Unity to the mix you also have to introduce a Web Request Lifetime Manager. Why is that? Why is it that sample applications like Nerddinner do not have a Web Request Lifetime Manager? What exactly does it do? Is it a Unity specific thing?

A second pattern I notice is the introduction of Unit of Work. Again, same question: Why does Nerddinner or ContactManager not use Unit of Work? Instead these applications use the repository classes on top of Linq2Sql or Entity Framework to do the data manipulation. No sign of any Unit of Work. What exactly is it and why should it be used?

Thanks

Below is a example of DI in Nerddiner at the DinnersController level:

```
    public DinnersController()
        : this(new DinnerRepository()) {
    }

    public DinnersController(IDinnerRepository repository) {
        dinnerRepository = repository;
    }
```

So am I right to assume that because of the first constructor the controller "owns" the DinnerRepository and it will therefore depend on the lifetime of the controller since it is declared there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Linq-to-SQL is used directly, your controller owns the reference to the data context. It's usually a private reference inside the controller, and so is created as part of its construction. There's no need in lifetime management, since it's in one place.

However, when you use IoC container, your data repository are created outside your controller. Since IoC container that creates it for you doesn't know how and how long you're going to use the created object, a lifetime strategy is introduced.

For example, data context (repository) is usually created at the beginning of the web request and destroyed at the end. However, for components that work with external web service, or some static mapper (e.g. logger) there's no need to create them each time. So you may want to say to create them once (i.e. singletone lifestyle).

All this happen because IoC container (like Unity) are designed to handle many situations, and they don't know your specific needs. For example, some applications use "conversation" transactions where NHibernate (or Entity Framework maybe) may last during several pages / web requests. IoC containers allow you to tweak objects lifetime to suit your needs. But as said this comes at price - since there's no single predefined strategy, you have to select one yourself.

Why NerdDinner and other applications do not use more advanced techniques is simply because they are intended to demonstrate MVC features, not advanced usages of some other libraries. I remember an article written to demonstrate one IoC container advanced functionality - this article broke some approved design patterns like separation of concerns - but this wasn't that important because design patterns were not the goal of the article. Same with simple MVC-demonstration-applications - they do not want you, the MVC newcomer, to be lost in IoC labyrinths.

And I would not recommend to look at Oxite as a design reference example:
http://codebetter.com/blogs/karlseguin/archive/2008/12/15/oxite-oh-dear-lord-why.aspx
http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/12/19/oxite-open-exchangable-informative-troubled-engine.aspx

Comment: Thank you! That helped. I have edited my question at the bottom. Is this what you mean when you say the controller owns the reference to the repository/data context?

Comment: Not exactly. In NerdDinner they use additional constructor accepting IDinnerRepository to make unit tests easier. But yes, it's still either controller (parameterless constructor) or tests that create and own the repository object. They both die and there're no other users of the repository; so lifetime is simple. By the way such technique is bad; you can read more about it here: http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/07/03/how-not-to-do-dependency-injection-in-nerddinner.aspx (as well as google for "poor man's IoC").

Comment: Jimmy Bogard's argument about this being a blatant example of "poor man's IoC" is extremely good here.  The comments are also good.  Definitely worth a read.

Answer (score 0):

Most if not all of the DI containers touch the concept of life times, I believe. Depending on the scenario involved, you may want the container to always return the same instance of a registered component, while for another component, you may want it to always return a new instance. Most containers also allow you to specify that within a particular context, you want it to return the same instance, etc..

I don't know Unity very well (so far I have used Windsor and Autofac), but I suspect the web request lifetime manager to be an implementation of lifetime strategies where the same instance is provided by the container during the lifetime of a single web request. You will find similar strategies in containers like Windsor.

Finally, I suppose you are referring to Unit of Work. A Unit of Work is in essence a group of actions that you want to succeed or fail as one atomic business transaction. For a more formal description, look at Martin Fowler's [definition](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html). It is a concept that has gained more popularity in the context of Domain Driven Design. A unit of work keeps track of the changes you apply in such a transaction, and when the time is right, it commits these changes in one ACID transaction. In NHibernate e.g., the session supports the notion of unit of work and more specifically the change tracking, while in Linq2SQL it is the Context ...